# random sample from 7 columns for 80 rows

Tags: r

i have a table with 7 columns and 80 rows that looks like this,

```
         **`1`   `3`   `5`   `7`   `9`  `11`
          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>**
      1     6     7     7     8    NA    NA
      2     6     7    13    13    14    NA
      3     9    10    10     8    NA    NA
      4     4     3     5     3    NA    NA
      5     3     2     5     5     6    NA
      6     7     7     5     4     5     5
      7     9     5     8     8    NA    NA
      8     6     6     7    NA     7    NA
      9    NA     6     5     5    NA    NA
     10     6     7     6     4     7     6
      # ... with 70 more rows
```

I need to make a random sample of one of the 7 columns for each row. For example row 1 (8) row 2 (6) row 3 (10) and so on for all 80 rows. Can I use the sample function and when yes then how? What can I do with the NAs. I need to do this sampling 1000 times and calculate the mean for each sample.

Any help will be highly appreciated!
Thanks,
Aldin

Comment: Do you want to sample also the `NA`s or you want to sample only not `NA` values?

Comment: NAs would influence the mean so I need to leave them out. More precisely , in a row with NAs  the sampling should always be done with present values. Is the entire row removed if I exclude the NAs from sampling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` to loop over the rows, get the non-NA elements and get the `sample`

```
n <- 1000
lst <- replicate(n, apply(df1, 1, function(x) sample(x[!is.na(x)], 1)),
               simplify = FALSE)
Reduce(`+`, lst)/n
```

---

or with `pmap` and `rowMeans`

```
library(tidyverse)
rowMeans(replicate(n, pmap_int(df1, ~
                          c(...) %>% 
                          na.omit %>%
                          sample(., 1))))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:9, NA), 80 * 7, replace = TRUE), 80, 7))
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I have tried the apply function and it gave me exactly what I needed. The next important question is how can I get the mean of the 80 randomly drawn observations from the 1000 replications. I need to get these 1000 means to analyse if they are significantly differrent from the mean of the sample measured in the lab. Hope you understand my question as its really complicated to describe.

Comment: @AldinSelimovic  That is the `replicate` step which does 1000 times the same thing and get the `mean` with `rowMeans` or `Reduce` with `+` and divide by length

Comment: UPDATE: I have used this function to get the means of the 1000 replications: mean2<- lapply(lst, mean)  Is this the correct way?

Comment: be careful - `sample` has a "feature" that may give you incorrect results (or no results). It can be triggered with: `df1[80,] <- c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)` then run `rowMeans...`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses plyr::adply.

```
library(plyr)

# original dataset
df1 <- data.frame(
   c( 6,  6,  9,  4,  3,  7,  9,  6, NA, 6),
   c( 7,  7, 10,  3,  2,  7,  5,  6,  6, 7),
   c( 7, 13, 10,  5,  5,  5,  8,  7,  5, 6),
   c( 8, 13,  8,  3,  5,  4,  8, NA,  5, 4),
   c(NA, 14, NA, NA,  6,  5, NA,  7, NA, 7),
   c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  5, NA, NA, NA, 6)
)


# returns a single column from a row with NA's removed
samplerow <- function(r) {
  # r is a single row of df
  # eliminate NAs from the dataset.
  r <- r[!is.na(r)]
  # Return one sample from this row
  # Not sure what happens if the row is all NAs. Don't do that.
  r[sample.int(length(r),1)]
}

N <- 1000
# for N times,
# for each row select 1 non-NA valued column,
# take the mean of all rows
replicate(N, mean(adply(df1, 1, samplerow, .expand=F)$V1))
#...redacted...
N <- 5
set.seed(1)
replicate(N, mean(adply(df1, 1, samplerow, .expand=F)$V1))
[1] 6.0 6.2 6.2 7.0 7.1
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked great.  Thanks to all of you for the help. This is a really great community!!!

Comment: Hi, the function worked great but what if I want to draw 2 or more columns?

Answer (score 2):

Use `sapply()`.

```
sapply(as.data.frame(t(df1)), function(x) sample(na.omit(x), 1))
```

***Data***

```
df1 <- structure(list(X.1. = c(6L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 6L, NA, 6L
), X.3. = c(7L, 7L, 10L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L), X.5. = c(7L, 
13L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 6L), X.7. = c(8L, 13L, 8L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, NA, 5L, 4L), X.9. = c(NA, 14L, NA, NA, 6L, 5L, 
NA, 7L, NA, 7L), X.11. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 
6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```